# Ubuntu 12.0.4 rails was working yesterday. Not today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I use rvm and installed it with this instructions https://rvm.io//rvm/install/.

Yesterday when I was working everything was just fine.

Today when I tried to start `rails s` it says

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

I have no idea how to make it work again. When I run `rvm gem list` it gives me this:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.4)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.3)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.3)
ansi (1.4.2)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.3)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.18)
multi_json (1.3.5)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
sass (3.1.19)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.9.5)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.4)
```

So does anybody have any idea why the rails stopped working? And I think it has something to do with when I shutdown the computer yesterday.

Comment: what's the result of `gem list`? Are you sure you are using the correct ruby version and the correct gemset? (try `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list` to see if it is your expected result)

Comment: It must be your system path.  Set the rails environment there.

Comment: please include outputs of `rvm get stable`, `rvm info` and `gem env`, my guess is that your `PATH` was restet after RVM set it.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it as root, you need to do `source /etc/profile`.

If you installed it for your own individual user, you should add `~/.rvm/scripts` to your `$PATH`